# what are callback frameworks?

Tags: frameworks

I am reading Effective Java and it has the following sentence.

> The disadvantages of wrapper classes are few. One caveat is that wrapper
>   classes are not suited for use in callback frameworks, wherein objects pass selfreferences
>   to other objects for subsequent invocations (“callbacks”).

Now what is a callback framework ? Can you point me to an example of call back framework ?

Comment: This sentence seems to be a bit out of context. Could you tell us in which section this sentence appears ?

Comment: Additionally: "Why are wrapper classes not suited for use in callback frameworks?"

Comment: @barjak this is from Chapter 4 (Classes and Interfaces), page 85.  http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA85&dq=wrapper%20class&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q=wrapper%20class&f=false

Comment: Ok, so the term "wrapper class" here refers to a class that uses composition instead of inheritance. And the caveat that is discussed in this paragraph happens when the "wrapped" class implements a callback interface and registers himself as a callback object. Personnaly, I think it's a bad style for a class to implement callback interfaces, anyway. So the caveat goes away...

Comment: If you mean the frameworks having callback classes , here is the list of frameworks having that - http://javasearch.buggybread.com/home.php?keyword=callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most GUI frameworks, and, SAX (Streaming XML) XML parsers use callbacks.

The basic pattern is that you pass an instance of a handler class (or sometimes just a method reference) when you initialize another class.  When a specific event occurs the "handler" class is called to deal with the event.

This is typically how you get your code to run when a button on a GUI is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

many gui frameworks are callback frameworks (functions are called as events happen)

any time you have to provide handlers for events you are using a callback framework