# Why are wrapper classes not suited for use in callback frameworks?

Tags: java, frameworks, event-programming

I just read the question [what are callback frameworks?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117434/what-are-callback-frameworks), where the asker cites the following from Effective Java:

> The disadvantages of wrapper classes are few. One caveat is that
>   wrapper classes are not suited for use in callback frameworks, wherein
>   objects pass selfreferences to other objects for subsequent
>   invocations (“callbacks”).

So I am curious, why are wrapper classes not suited for use in callback frameworks? And can you provide an example of what the problem is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next line of Effective Java is helpful in clarifying the issue:

> "Because a wrapped object doesn't know of its wrapper, it passes a
>   reference to itself(**this**) and callbacks elude the wrapper.  This is
>   known as the *SELF problem* [Lieberman86]."

It seems like a trivial thing to make sure that all references to an object are via its wrapper, but wrappers are generally injected when a need arises and their design (their entire purpose of being) is to provide a *low friction* way to add more functionality to an existing class.  This leads to subtle bugs, like the wrapper missing the event.  Or the wrapper and wrapped object both registering for the same events - leading to duplicate processing and potential concurrency issues as well.  If you don't know (don't have the source code) where callbacks are registered, it may be impossible to work around this problem.  Additionally, wrappers are based on "pure" composition principles and callback frameworks force a "dirty" wrapper design.

Answer (score 2):

```
    interface SomethingWithCallback {

      void doSomething();

      void call();

    }


    class WrappedObject implements SomethingWithCallback {

      private final SomeService service;

      WrappedObject(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
      }

      @Override
      public void doSomething() {
        service.performAsync(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void call() {
        System.out.println("WrappedObject callback!");
      }
    }


    class Wrapper implements SomethingWithCallback {

      private final WrappedObject wrappedObject;

      Wrapper(WrappedObject wrappedObject) {
        this.wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
      }

      @Override
      public void doSomething() {
        wrappedObject.doSomething();
      }

      void doSomethingElse() {
        System.out.println("We can do everything the wrapped object can, and more!");
      }

      @Override
      public void call() {
        System.out.println("Wrapper callback!");
      }
    }

    final class SomeService {

      void performAsync(SomethingWithCallback callback) {
        new Thread(() -> {
          perform();
          callback.call();
        }).start();
      }

      void perform() {
        System.out.println("Service is being performed.");
      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeService   service       = new SomeService();
        WrappedObject wrappedObject = new WrappedObject(service);
        Wrapper       wrapper       = new Wrapper(wrappedObject);
        wrapper.doSomething();
    }
```

The problem is that even though we called doSomething() on the wrapper, the callback of the wrapped object got called, not the callback of the wrapper. This is what Joshua Bloch refers to when he says that "callbacks elude the wrapper".

Reference: [Link](https://coderanch.com/t/670687/java/wrapper-class-suitable-callback-framework)